# Cannot find a solution for a budget expenditure maximisation problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a DP problem which consists on the following:

Let's say that we are a town hall with a budget `B` and have a set of projects `P`, each one with a cost `p_i` to build. Since the town hall's budget leftovers at the end of the year will not carry to the next one, they want to maximize the expenditure as much as possible.

Due to this, they want to find the maximum possible cost they can have by approving projects from `P`, without surpassing the maximum budget `B`.

So far, I have established the following recurrence relation/equation:

```
    maxCost (B, i) = 
        if (B >= p_i)
             // Since the budget allows it, choose the maximum between approving this 
             // project and evaluating the previous one with a smaller budget, or not 
             // approving it and evaluating the previous one with the same budget
             max{maxCost(B-p_i, i - 1) + p_i, maxCost(B, i - 1)} 
        else
             // Since the budget does not allow approving the current project, check the
             // previous one with the same budget
             maxCost(B, i - 1)

Additionally, maxCost (B, i) = 0 if i > length(P) ||  j < 1 (or 0, if 0-indexed)
```

The memoization structure can be a cost array `C` of size `B` (ignoring memory issues if `B` is enormous, or non-integer), where we always fill it from the right (we will always consult `C`for the evaluation of the previous project, for values smaller than the current budget, and write onto `C[B]`). The initial values for `C` will all be `0`.

The problem appears when writing the algorithm itself, which translates to replacing `maxCost(B, i)` with `C[B]`, keeping and updating `B` as a variable depending on which choice is made (approve or pass onto the next project), and iterating over the projects from the first one to the last one.

If the algorithm is done like that, any mock example will show that the solution is not optimal (it behaves more like a greedy algorithm), since the budget is subtracted unconditionally from the start and later projects will not be able to get approved, even if they were better choices.

For example, for:

```
    B = 50
    P = [10, 20, 40]
    C = [0, 0, ... , 0] (size 50)
```

The algorithm will choose to approve the first and second projects, and the third project will not get approved since `B(30)<40`, but the optimal solution would be approving the first and third projects.

Is there something missing from the equations, or is the implementation for this case special? I have been unable to find a similar base problem for this one, so I couldn't find similar solutions.

Comment: The only way to guarantee the best possible outcome is to go through every single possible combination of projects.  There are no algorithmic short-cuts; you either brute-force it *(check every single possibility)*, or you accept an approximation with various cases that can't be handled well.  If you have a particularly large search space, I recommend looking in to Genetic Algorithm approaches.

Comment: @MatBailie But a DP solution like this goes through every single combination "recursively", doesn't it? It basically chooses between approving or not one project, after testing the same thing for every other project before/after that one

Comment: @MatBailie this is a known Dynamic Programming solution of 0-1 knapsack problem (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving) with O(n*B) time and space complexity, which is feasible if 'budget' B is a natural number and sufficiently small (or rational number which has sufficiently small product of numerator and denominator in reduced form).

Comment: Your memoization array should be 2-dimensional and memoize directly the result of maxCost function: `C[B, i] = maxCost(B, i);`. Moreover, you can directly compute `C` array by iterating over `B` in outer loop and `i` in inner loop  avoiding using `maxCost` function altogether. In DP it's usually done like this.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk That was it, thank you very much! Doing the memoization as a 1-dimensional array and keeping the budget as a variable was causing the weird mix between a greedy and a DP solution,